# Not able to enter my Amazon Access Keys in AmazonSimpleAdmin

Tags: amazon-web-services, wordpress

I tried to register my Amazon Account in AmazonSimpleAdmin (which is a plugin for Wordpress to show Amazon Affiliates on my blog.

After entering my Amazon Access Key ID and my Secret Access Key I got following error:
"Error: AWS.InvalidAccount: Your AccessKey Id is not registered for Product Advertising API. Please use the AccessKey Id obtained after registering at https://affiliate-program.amazon.co.uk/gp/flex/advertising/api/sign-in.html
Get help at http://www.wp-amazon-plugin.com/faq/#setup_errors"

I tried without success:
* deleting my two Amazon Access Keys and recreated a new one.
* I double-checked if I had typos in the keys.

Comment: Make sure you're not using the Access Key ID/Secret Access Key from an IAM user. When you first open the IAM dashboard, a popup appears. Did you choose **Continue to Security Credentials** or **Get Started with IAM Users**?

Comment: thx, no I've chosen Secutiry Credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two Amazon account. I mixed them up accidentially.
After I followed the instructions [here](http://www.wp-amazon-plugin.com/register-amazon-affiliate-product-advertising-api/?#13) step-by-step, I finally succeed.